# Projective resolution of Laurent polynomials

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb C[t_1,t_1^{-1},\ldots,t_n,t_n^{-1}]$ be the ring of Laurent polynomials in $n$ variables.
I am looking for a projective resolution of $A$ as an $A$-bimodule that be as explicit as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finding resolutions of the canonical bimodule $A$ can be difficult. What have you tried? Did you do the $n=1$ case? What did you find there?

Comment: Note that if you want to compute Hochschild (co)homology, you can use that it behaves well with localisation!